# Applescript - activate background application doesn't work

Tags: macos, applescript

Why doesn't this work

```
tell application "System Events"
    set AppName to name of every process whose background only is false
    tell application (some item of AppName)
        activate
    end tell
end tell
```

while this

works

```
global AppName
tell application "System Events"
    set AppName to name of every process whose background only is false
end tell

tell application (some item of AppName)
    activate
end tell
```

Obviously, it has something to do with scope but I don't understand why or what.

Comment: It's not about scope, no, it's about where commands are being directed to and which application or script is handling their execution.  You nested one `tell application` block inside the other in your first script.  There are many good reasons to do this in a given situation, but this isn't one of them as _System Events_ can't really issue commands to other applications, and `activate` is ambiguously targetting potentially both _System Events_ and some other application, so likely ends up activating _System Events_ preferentially.  Separating the two `tell` blocks in your second is what works.

Comment: The `global AppName` declaration is redundant.

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem is..  Telling an application to activate, is handled by "Standard Additions", but you are asking "System Events" to handle that action.

```
tell application "System Events" to set AppName to name of ¬
    every process whose background only is false
tell application (some item of AppName) to activate
```

Comment: You don't need `my`.  `tell application (some item of AppName) to activate` is sufficient.

Comment: Yes you are correct.  However, I do believe if you set the variable within an application tell block, referring to that variable in a tell block of a different application, using "my" or "of it" becomes necessary.  I think LOL

Comment: That's in relation to properties and handlers, not variables, does it not ?

Answer (score 4):

Let me tell you a story:

One parent got up and called to three children:

- Ace - wake up and go bring me an apple
- Deuce - wake up and go bring me an apple
- Trey - wake up and go bring me an apple

That parent was happy to have three apples and everyone out of bed.

The other parent said:

- Trey - wake up and go bring me an apple (or they think they asked Trey - they're not really sure they were specific about what or who was asked)

Does this match what "doesn't work" for you?

If so - awesome. If not, you'll want to step through each script in Script Editor and see where your programs go "off script". I would also encourage a look at https://latenightsw.com Script Debugger - it runs some basic functionality for free, but If you value your time more than you do stepping through scripts in Apple's more basic editor, it may be worth the $$ to you for the full version.

Also, a book on iteration or loops might be a good place to go if everything wasn't clear. Don't feel bad, this is a great place to stumble and learn - once you get loops, you'll be able to do amazing things in any scripting language - not just AppleScript.

Comment: I really hope you earned your 145k reputation with answers exactly like this one.  This is brilliant.  I wish all StackExchange answers were abstract parables.

Comment: Ouch - I think ;)

Comment: No, I genuinely love this answer.  I don't necessarily want to +1 it, but I definitely want to ❤ it.

Comment: Well @CJK then I really appreciate the kind comment. That's really what drives me and not any specific +1 or -1 and I get that sometimes this abstract an answer really doesn't land well and I get that, too.

Comment: Love it! :) Storytelling is definitely one of the best ways to teach and/or convey a message!

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to click the "OK" button on Kontakt in the background while I worked. This solved my issue:

```
tell application "System Events"
    if exists of application process "Kontakt 5" then
        tell application "Kontakt 5.6.0" to activate
        delay 0.5
        repeat
            try
                click UI element "OK" of window 1 of application process "Kontakt 5"
            end try
        end repeat
    end if
end tell
```